# How can I order EZ Publish activeextensions in site.ini.append?

Tags: php, ezpublish

I'm new to EZ Publish. but when I had to change some CSS files, I made a mistake thinking I have to modify something in: /settings/override/site.init.append.php

The file now looks like this:

[ExtensionSettings]

- ActiveExtensions[]
- ActiveExtensions[]=ezscriptmonitor
- ActiveExtensions[]=ezmultiupload
- ActiveExtensions[]=ez_network
- ActiveExtensions[]=ezjscore
- ActiveExtensions[]=cjw_newsletter
- ActiveExtensions[]=ezwt
- ActiveExtensions[]=ezstarrating
- ActiveExtensions[]=ezgmaplocation
- ActiveExtensions[]=ezwebin
- ActiveExtensions[]=ezie
- ActiveExtensions[]=ezoe
- ActiveExtensions[]=ezodf
- ActiveExtensions[]=ezprestapiprovider
- ActiveExtensions[]=proceli
- ActiveExtensions[]=xrowmetadata

I guess I have to change the order of some of this extensions, but I don't know the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

actually the order of extensions depend on what they need and how they should override each other.
So no one can exactly tell you which one should come first and which one second without knowing what they are doing!

Answer (score 0):

If some of your extensions need to be loaded in a specific order (for instance if you want a specific one to override another one), then as of eZ Publish Fuji, there's a behavior called 'Extension load ordering' which can help a bit : https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.4/Installation/Extensions/Extension-load-ordering

That said, and usually, you must put the more specific extensions (such as the one containing your project design) at the top of the list, and the less specific (such as ezoe, ezodf, ezwebin, etc...) at the bottom of the list. Custom but purely technical extensions (such as a custom datatype or module) would reside in the middle of the list.

If you want to rollback to the original order, I'd suggest to make a fresh install in a separate documentroot/virtualhost.

Hope this helps